# titleView jumps after segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UISplitViewController` as rootViewController. The masterViewController of this `UISplitViewController` sets a `UIView` with a `UITextField` centered inside it as `titleView`. This is wat it looks like in the storyboard.[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-((self.view.frame.size.width/2)+150))/2, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width/2)+150, 30)];

    self.rightButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [self.rightButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(barButtonRight:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        self.rightButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.rightButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.rightButton];
        self.splitViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

    self.textField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
        self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.titleView.frame.size.width, 30);
    } else {
        self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(65, 0, (self.view.frame.size.width-20)-110, 30);
    }
    self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    if (IDIOM == IPAD) {
        UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 20)];
        self.textField.leftView = paddingView;
        self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }
    [self.titleView addSubview:self.textField];

    self.splitViewController.navigationItem.titleView = self.titleView;
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Now, when a the right button is pressed a strange thing happens.

```
- (IBAction)barButtonRight:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}
```

The `UITextField` is pushed all the way to the left inside the `UIView`. I commented out most of my `viewDidLoad` code and this is still happening. Any ideas as to what's causing this?

Comment: are using autolayout, and is this happen in ipad or iphone

Comment: On iPad without autolayout.

Comment: put your code or something that we can help

Comment: I added it to the question.